# Break down sections in a text file using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a file which is in this format

```
name.css  value
  name.js  value
```

I want to break this down and create strings which will be in this format
     string1  =  "c:\" + value + name + extension(css or js)
can someone please tell me how to do this in vbscript.

So far I am looking to break this into dictionary and then loop through and creating new dim objects which loops through the whole file and creates values but not getting it right.Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You really should present your real world problem in a short story.

Comment: Not getting your point..I just tried to generalize my issue

Comment: You tried but you failed; e.g. "break down sections" - how many sections does your sample contain? "create strings" vs "create new dim objects" vs "create values"? "dictionary" - what (unique) keys? how should the generated file specs be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\s+"
re.Global  = True

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\your\input.txt")
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  tokens = Split(Trim(re.Replace(f.ReadLine, " ")))
  WScript.Echo "C:\" & tokens(1) & tokens(0)
Loop
f.Close
```

Comment: +1 - especially for the Trim() which hopefully does not loose the info needed for the 'breaking into sections'.

Comment: super good..Can you also tell me how while looping I can create like an incremental token dim variable like token1 token2 token3 etc till the loop ends.

Comment: @user505210 What do you need this for?